# Creating a manual plot legend

Tags: plotting

Using the command,

```
    A = Show[
  Graphics[{Black, Thick, Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {0, Pi}], Darker[Red], 
    Circle[{0.5, 0}, 0.5, {0, Pi}], Circle[{-0.5, 0}, 0.5, {0, Pi}], 
    Blue, Circle[{0.75, 0}, 0.25, {0, Pi}], 
    Circle[{0.25, 0}, 0.25, {0, Pi}], 
    Circle[{-0.25, 0}, 0.25, {0, Pi}], 
    Circle[{-0.75, 0}, 0.25, {0, Pi}], Darker[Green], 
    Circle[{(-1 - 0.75)/2, 0}, Abs[(-1 - 0.75)/2 - (-0.75)], {0, Pi}],
     Circle[{(-0.75 - 0.5)/2, 0}, 
     Abs[(-0.75 - 0.5)/2 - (-0.5)], {0, Pi}], 
    Circle[{(-0.5 - 0.25)/2, 0}, 
     Abs[(-0.5 - 0.25)/2 - (-0.25)], {0, Pi}], 
    Circle[{(-0.25 - 0)/2, 0}, 
     Abs[(-0.25 - 0.00)/2 - (-0.00)], {0, Pi}], 
    Circle[{(1 + 0.75)/2, 0}, Abs[(1 + 0.75)/2 - (0.75)], {0, Pi}], 
    Circle[{(0.75 + 0.5)/2, 0}, Abs[(0.75 + 0.5)/2 - (0.5)], {0, Pi}],
     Circle[{(0.5 + 0.25)/2, 0}, 
     Abs[(0.5 + 0.25)/2 - (0.25)], {0, Pi}], 
    Circle[{(0.25 + 0)/2, 0}, 
     Abs[(0.25 - 0.00)/2 - (0.00)], {0, Pi}]}], 
  Plot[0, {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[Large]}], 
  Frame -> True, Background -> LightBlue]
```

I have the following plot:

[image]

I want to include a legend where I label the plot manually. For instance, I want to label the dark red set of curves with the label "first iteration," because I got this curve by applying a recursive definition for value k = 1.

How would I go about implementing such a scheme?

Answer (score 3):

```
Legended["YourPlot",
  Placed[LineLegend[{Red,Green,Blue,"Your Color"},   
        {"Label1","Label2",..."LabelX"}],
    Scaled@{0.5,0.5}]]
```

You can use another Legend objects instead `LineLegend` (see help for it for details). The scaled coordinates defines the position of the legend in the figure.